# imagick unable to read the file

Tags: php, jquery, imagemagick

I have following php code in a file:

```
$figloc = $_GET['figrl'];

try
{
$image = new Imagick($figloc);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->setImageColorSpace(5);  
$image->writeImage("temp.jpg");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and a jquery script like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    figurelocation='temp.jpg';
    var fightmlstring='<img src=\"'+figurelocation+'\">';
    $('.figuredisplay').append(fightmlstring);
});
```

figuredisplay is a div element. $figloc value is the absolute address of the image on disk, like '/home/abc/def/ghi/jkl.tiff'. The php file, when opened from appropriate link, shows the error message "imagick unable to open file /home/abc/def/ghi/jkl.tiff". Can the absolute address cause a problem?

Also, when I copied a particular tiff file to my directory, to see if the absolute address was a problem, imagick possessedly read that file, but failed to create temp.jpg

```
unable to open image `/var/www/temp.jpg @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489
```

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the file on the servers disk? Absolute paths do not mean the server can read the clients disk on which the browser runs.

Comment: The file is on server's disk. I also checked the permission it's -rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: And what does [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/is_readable) say about the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. This was a really silly one. I am writing so others facing the same problem may benefit.

Instead of

```
$image = new Imagick($figloc);
```

write:

```
$abc= substr ( $figloc , 1, strlen($figloc)-2);
$image = new Imagick($figloc);
```

So, the single quotes from the figloc string are removed. Really silly :-)